# Como pasar datos entre dos Activity y posteriormente a Fragments

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

soy nuevo programando con android y mucho le sabré agradecer si me podrían ayudar a completar esta tarea.

Cuento con una actividad A que muestra una lista de datos a través de un RecyclerView y un CardView (Datos obtenidos desde SqlServer). Todo funciona bien hasta acá, la idea es cargar el detalle de los datos en una actividad B (Tabbed Activity) que posteriormente los muestre en dos fragments. Hasta ahora he podido llevar los datos desde la actividad A hasta la actividad B, pero no logro enlazar un TextView con el dato obtenido. alguna sugerencia? De antemano, gracias!

MOSTRANDO LOS DATOS EN EL CARD (ACTIVITY A) Y POSTERIORMENTE ENVIÁNDOLOS AL TAB (ACTIVITY B):

```
    public class  ListArtAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListArtAdapter.ArtViewHolder> {

    private List<Art> items;

    public static class ArtViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public CardView art_cardviev;
        public ImageView dis_cen;
        public TextView co_art;

        public ArtViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            art_cardviev = view.findViewById(R.id.art_cardview);
            dis_cen = view.findViewById(R.id.dis_cen);
            co_art = view.findViewById(R.id.co_art);
    }

        // Metodo para crear el adaptador que recibe como parametro la lista de articulos
        public ListArtAdapter(List<Art> items){
            this.items = items;
        }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ArtViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_list_art_cardview, viewGroup, false);
        return new ArtViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ArtViewHolder artViewHolder, final int i) {
        artViewHolder.dis_cen.setImageResource(items.get(i).getDis_cen());
        artViewHolder.co_art.setText(items.get(i).getCo_art());

        //Asignando envento click al activity_list_art_cardview declarado al principio
        artViewHolder.art_cardviev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            //Pasamos los datos a la actividad TabArtActivity
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("curDis_cen", items.get(i).getDis_cen());
                bundle.putString("curCo_art", items.get(i).getCo_art());

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), TabArtActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ADAPTADOR DEL TAB ACTIVITY

```
public class TabArtAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    @StringRes
    private static final int[] TAB_TITLES = new int[]{R.string.txt_detalles, R.string.txt_valores};
    private final Context mContext;

    public TabArtAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                DetailArtFragment detailArtFragment = new DetailArtFragment();
                return detailArtFragment;
            case 1:
                AmountArtFragment amountArtFragment = new AmountArtFragment();
                return amountArtFragment;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mContext.getResources().getString(TAB_TITLES[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 2;
    }
}
```

RECIBIENDO LOS DATOS EN EL ACTIVITY B

```
public class TabArtActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_art);

        TabArtAdapter tabArtAdapter = new TabArtAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabArtAdapter);

        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String co_art = bundle.getString("curCo_art");

        Bundle bundleDetail = new Bundle();
        bundleDetail.putString("curCo_art",co_art);

        DetailArtFragment detailArtFragment = new DetailArtFragment();
        detailArtFragment.setArguments(bundleDetail);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Prueba" + co_art, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

FRAGMENTO QUE MUESTRA LA INFORMACION OBTENIDA EN EL ACTIVITY B

public class DetailArtFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView co_art;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_art, container, false);
        co_art = v.findViewById(R.id.co_art);
        //co_art.setText(getArguments().getString("curCo_art"));

        String codigo = this.getArguments().getString("curCo_art").toString();
        co_art.setText(codigo);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es mostrar el detalle de un item en un fragment n?, tiene que haber varios ejemplos por aqui busca bien, 
Para pasar dato de activ a activ se realiza con intem, para hacerlo de activ a fragment con bundle, tienes que capturar el id del objeto que quieres mostar los datos para asi saber cual es que quieres mostrar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu problema es que estas mostrando un DetailArtFragment creado en el adapter, pero el bundle se lo estas pasando a un DetailArtFragment que luego no usas, por eso no estas viendo los datos en el Fragment.

Para resolver el problema pasale los datos al Adapter y que este luego se los pase al Fragment cuando los cree.
No hay misterio en como pasarle parametros al adapter, solo agregale una funcion `public void setDetailArtFragmentBundle(dundle Bundle)` y guardate el bundle en una propiedad del adapter para darselo al DetailArtFragment al momento de instanciarlo.

Lo demas a mi entender deberia estar funcionando.